# how to omit program points in Daikon invariant detector?

Tags: java, automated-tests, invariants

I am using `Daikon` (likely program invariant detector) to generate invariants for a simple java class with different methods. I wanted to omit few methods from this class which I achieved through the following command:

```
java daikon.Chicory '--ppt-omit-pattern=C0.printRangeFail()|C0.printRangePass()|C0.main()|C0.failureDomain()' C0
```

The tool also provide the option to skip invariants at certain points like ENTER, EXIT etc. Now I want to skip the method EXIT point. I appended the following text to the command but no luck.

`checkFirstAndLastValue():::EXIT`

Can you please help me how to omit the following method from Daikons output.

`C0.checkFirstAndLastValue(int, int):::EXIT`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Daikon manual](http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon/download/doc/daikon.html#Processing-only-part-of-the-trace-file), the argument to the --ppt-omit-pattern command-line argument is a regular expression.  In a regular expression, "()" matches nothing.  If you want to match parentheses, you should quote them in the regular expression.

I suspect that something like this would work better:

```
java daikon.Chicory '--ppt-omit-pattern=C0\.printRangeFail\(\)|C0\.printRangePass\(\)|C0\.main\(\)|C0\.failureDomain\(\)|C0\.checkFirstAndLastValue\(\):::EXIT' C0
```